# Existe uma única forma de usar imagens no pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

Eu li na documentação que existe o método `image.load` para ler imagens, porém ele retorna um objeto do tipo `Surface` que nem sempre é o mais adequado, então eu queria saber se existe uma forma de retornar um objeto do tipo `Rect`. E também queria saber como usar uma imagem de um sprite no pygame?

Comment: É possível escrever uma ótima resposta para essa dúvida, mas meu conhecimento de Pygame é limitado. Talvez alguma parte dessa documentação possa te ajudar: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html

Answer (score 1):

Olá tudo bem? acredito que o que busca é o método get_rect(). Todas as superfícies o tem, basta usar está imagem que você carregou.

Exemplo: *imagem.get_rect()*.

Espero ter ajudado.